# Strange texture paint artifacts

Tags: texture-painting, artifacts

I'm trying to paint on my 3D model. UV's are unwrapped with no stretching. Texture is 1024x1024 with alpha. Brush has alpha check as well (I've fiddled with all the brush settings, couldn't find solution).When I try to paint this happens:

[image: Screen gif]

This is my UV setup:

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: can you share your blend file or show a screen capture of your UV map ?

Comment: @lemon I've edited the question, thank for the bump

Comment: Are you painting using a texture ? That may be something like you are painting on the same image as your paint texture is linked to. I think you do not need a painting texture here.

Comment: Please show settings of your paint brush. It is visible in your screenshot that there are options of the brush texture in the Properties window in the right side; it reminds patterns appearing while you draw. I don't *think* this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it took awhile, but the answer is right there in your screen shot - you have loaded your image canvas as your brush texture, so as you paint it becomes your brush projected onto itself.

Your image needs only to be loaded as your material texture slot, not in the brush. Load something else as the image in that brush texture and you will then see it repeated along the surface....